# Xcode View Controller - Horizontal orientation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I have got two view controllers on a Storyboard in Xcode.  If I Build and run the application with the initial View controller set as the startup item (The app only allows horizontal orientation) then the application in the Simulator is displayed correctly with all the images in the correct place in Horizontal orientation.

However if I add another View controller to the Storyboard (setting this as the startup item).  The simulator is run and displayed horizontally however the graphics are being displayed as if the screen is in vertical orientation.

The plist looks correct and also I have tried setting up the simulated metrics to Landscape and Full Screen.  However this does not seem to have worked. The display looks correct within Xcode.  It is just when I come to run it on the simulator.

I have searched across Google and have come across articles on Rotating iPads and Orientations.

Can anyone help with my issue?  Do I need to add any extra code to get my new view controller to be recognised in the horizontal orientation?  or is this a bug with simluator?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the answer to the question myself and I thought I would share.

All I needed to do was select the ViewController Class in the Utilities Screen.

I assume by doing this it can invoke the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method and also know which way around the screen should be.